# Unable to delete restore point in Azure backup

Tags: azure, azure-vm, azure-backup-vault, azure-disk

I hope someone can help me because I've been looking for a solution for hours.

I have created a VM in Azure and enabled backup. This morning I deleted the VM, and the recovery service vault I created for my backups.

Deletion of the VM and recovery service vault was successful. However, a restore point collection has been left behind which I cannot delete. When I open the collection I see that there is 1 snapshot present, but I cannot delete it either.

When I remove it I get the following error:

[image]

In the log I find the following text:

**There is an active shared access signature outstanding for disk restore point**

Anyone have any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: You can refer this [Troubleshoot restore point failures - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/restore-point-troubleshooting#diskrestorepointusedbycustomer---there-is-an-active-shared-access-signature-outstanding-for-disk-restore-point)

Comment: I know, troubleshoot anwser is "You can't delete a restore point if there are active Shared Access Signatures (SAS) on any of the underlying disk restore points. End the shared access on the disk restore points and retry the operation."

But the problem is: the disk doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Are you still unable to delete snapshot?

Comment: Yes still unable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved with help of support engineers, it was necessary to revoke SAS access of the disk restore point via the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/disk-restore-point/revoke-access?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0

Unfortunately it was not possible to do this via the Azure portal as the snapshot itself was already deleted.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results***

I have created one *VM* and enabled backup for it by creating recovery vault.

After some time, I tried to delete those, and everything got deleted successfully except the **snapshot**.

*I got the same error as you like below while performing above action*:

[image]

Please note that, the snapshot state is **`ActiveSAS`** which is why you are getting the error.

**To resolve the issue, you have to cancel the export like below:**

*Go to Azure Portal -> Your resource group -> Your Snapshot -> Snapshot export -> Cancel export*

[image]

***After cancelling the export, I'm able to delete the snapshot successfully as snapshot state is **`Unattached`** like below:***

[image]

After deleting the snapshot, I deleted **restore point** successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: Hi Sridevi, Thank you for your help!

Unfortunately it was not possible to do this via the Azure portal as the snapshot itself was already deleted.

But the problem has been solved , it was necessary to revoke SAS access of the disk restore point via the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/disk-restore-point/revoke-access?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0